# Performance Counters: How can I have more than 1 AverageBase in a given category?

Tags: c#, performancecounter

Suppose I have a category that contains 2 AverageTimer32 counters: AverageRead and AverageWrite. How do I give them both a Base? I mean if I add 2 AverageBase counters: AverageReadbase and AverageWritebase, how does the framework know which base belongs to which AverageTimer32 counter? The name? Or is that not possible within the same category?

Answer (score 1):

A base counter is associated with its parent counter by position.

See also: [How do performance counter average timers get associated with their base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418998/how-do-performance-counter-average-timers-get-associated-with-their-base)